# Functional Programming practice in Angular service files

Tags: typescript

It looks like Angular is heavily based on OOP paradigm which has classes, inheritances and so on.
However, in the service files, there are a lot of functions. Some functions call some other functions for business logic. The data almost comes from arguments passed by components functions.
May the project I'm working on is not totally OOP, since models contain nothing but model fields, so there's no function in models.
From above aspects, I think about applying FP (functional Programming) practices to the service files such as pure functions, immutability,... Since service files are just classes with a lot of functions.
But once I create a pipe function, my colleagues say it strange and hard to read the function on 'current' OOP paradigm

```
function pipe(...fns) {
    return data => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), data);
}
```

and use it something like this

```
const value = pipe(foo1,foo2(x),foo3)(data);
```

Do you think this is a good practice or not?
Does this make my project OOP mixed with FP?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The problem with questions like this is that they are almost impossible to answer. The answer could be yes or no, based on a lot of factors like requirements, architecture, composition of your team etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Service** is an already reserved name from Angular's ecosystem, I like to name this files as **Utilities** or **Utils**.

There are very useful and easy to read and easy to test, and sometimes they can carry important parts of my project.

For example there is `date.utils.ts` that will carry all the date utilities that I will need in a project or more deep a `car.utils.ts` will have some useful functions for an entity.

But, there are some downsides here:

1. Is very difficult to keep **State** and control data flows. If you try, it may be more complicated than it should.
2. You won't pass through **DI**, so If you need injected dependencies you have to pass them as parameters and that will end up pretty ugly.